# Is there a way to determine the Windows Phone Marketplace status?

Tags: music, video, store, xbox-live

The XBox Live, Music + Videos, and Marketplace tiles on my Windows Phone 7.5 are not currently working (they just return me to the page where the tile is located).  Other tiles seem to be working fine.

Is there a web page that shows the status of the Windows Phone Marketplace somewhere (since all 3 tiles would appear to have a connection to the marketplace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour does not sounds like a service disruption, but something wrong on your phone. These apps do not need a connection to the servers in order to open - you would instead be seeing the marketplace open, then give you an error message saying it was unavailable, and the music and games hub are designed to work with no data connection at all. Did anything change on your phone recently, when they stopped working? Have you tried rebooting?

If there were a service disruption, there is no one status page, but you could try checking the [official blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2011/05/05/marketplace-status.aspx) for a major outage, blogs like [wmpoweruser.com](http://wmpoweruser.com/) for any phone related incidents, or the [Xbox Live status page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status) for xbox live specific problems,

Comment: Rebooting did in fact fix my problem, thanks.